# git, how to I go back to origin master after pulling a branch

Tags: git

This has to be a FAQ, but I can't find it googling.

Another person created a branch, commit'd to it, and pushed it to github using
git push origin newbranch

I successfully pulled it down using

```
git pull origin newbranch
```

Now, I want to go back to the origin master version.
Nothing I do seems to cause the files in the origin master to replace those in the newbranch.

```
git checkout master
git checkout origin master
git pull
git pull origin HEAD
etc
```

`git pull origin master` returns:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

This can't be hard, but I sure can't figure it out.

'git branch' returns

```
* master
```

and 'git branch -r' return

```
  origin/HEAD
  origin/experimental
  origin/master
```

Comment: what does the output of "git branch" say after you do "git checkout master"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work to do what you need:

```
git checkout origin/master
```

Comment: Aye if you want to undo the pull into your master.

Comment: I'm a noob on this stuff, but yeah, I wanted to "revert to master" from the branch.

Answer (score 2):

Next time, maybe you can use git fetch first, after that, use git merge.

This will make your operation more clear.

Br,
Tim

Comment: Thanks, I have just been reading about git fetch. It wasn't covered in the tutorials that I've been reading.